# Is it possible to use resources in VPC from NextJS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, server-side-rendering, amazon-vpc

Suppose we have some services (RDS SQL databases, redis clusters e etc) that can only be accessed from resources inside a VPC. Is it possible to put Nextjs SSR lambda instances (I can be wrong, but I think the ssr is handled by lambdas) inside the VPC and make them access those services?

Comment: Yes, you can [connect Lambda functions to your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) so that they can access private resources such as RDS databases, cache/search clusters etc. An authenticated client would make an API request to your back-end via API Gateway which would invoke your Lambda function. The private resources e.g. RDS would have to be configured to allow inbound network traffic from the Lambda function, of course. I don't think that your choice of SSR or CSR is all that germane in this regard.

Comment: VPC can be thought of as a piece of Internet containing some resources and surrounded by a “shell”. This shell can identify traffic (whether inbound or outbound, protocol, IP etc.) and either pass it through or block it. You can either put your resource (doesn’t matter which kind) inside the VPC, or you can create a rule specifically for the traffic coming from your VPC-external resource; from the point of view of the VPC, it would be an inbound traffic. All this is done in the “Security groups” section of AWS VPC.

Comment: Keep in mind (I don’t know how much experience with AWS you have) that this might not be the only thing that you have to do to connect to your resource (e.g., setup SSL and whatnot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing the same problem but, unfortunately this seems not possible at the moment. A similar question was answered on AWS re:Post by the Amplify team.

> Amplify Next.js Classic SSR, the API routes are powered by L@E
> functions so there is no scope for configuring the same in VPC.
> Recently there is launch of Amplify Hosting Compute even that does not
> have VPC configuration. So what you are looking for is currently not
> supported, RDS needs to be open to public. However we do not recommend
> making the DB public as it does not seem secure. As a workaround, you
> may spin up an Amplify Backend to provision a Rest API + Lambda(VPC)
> that interacts with their RDS.

Source: [AWS re:Post](https://repost.aws/zh-Hant/questions/QUaqTDfgxWSEOLwbzsWhfnNg/next-js-on-amplify-how-to-connect-to-an-rds-database?sc_ichannel=ha&sc_ilang=en&sc_isite=repost&sc_iplace=hp&sc_icontent=QUaqTDfgxWSEOLwbzsWhfnNg&sc_ipos=13)